# Make inner joins by using Q objects in Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm customizing a model's Admin change list page in my project.

This model contains a Many to Many field and I want to allow multi-selection filtering.

I've used the [Django Admin Multi Select Filter package](https://github.com/JobDoesburg/django-admin-multi-select-filter) to do this but I noticed that the default behaviour in Django's `__in` lookup is to be inclusive and not exclusive.

Imagine I have an object A associated with M2M objects 1 and 2 and object B associated with M2M objects 2 and 3. If I make the following query `Model.objects.filter(m2m_model__in=[1,2])` I will have both objects A and B being retrieved, since the search will use the following condition:

`Index Cond: (models_model_m2mfield.model_id = ANY ('{1,2}'::bigint[]))`

I was able to customize the behaviour of the search by doing the following:

```
            for choice in choices:
                queryset = queryset.filter(**{self.lookup_kwarg: choice})
```

This generates inner joins and returns the value I'm waiting for (only objects matching every option).

```
INNER JOIN "models_model_m2mfield" ON ("models_m2mmodel"."id" = "models_model_m2mfield"."m2mfield_id") INNER JOIN "models_model_m2mfield" T4 ON ("models_m2mmodel"."id" = T4."m2mfield_id") WHERE ("models_model_m2mfield"."model_id" = 4 AND T4."model_id" = 5)
```

I've tried using Q objects to get the same result, but I couldn't make it work. Is it possible to achieve the same behaviour using the Q class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to achieve the same behaviour using the Q class?

**No**, you can not do this with a single `Q` object.

If you use two (or more) [**`.filter(…)`** clauses <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#filter) that JOIN on the same model, it will result in separate `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s on the same table. So that is why this will work. This is what we need, but it can, especially if not optimized quite well, in a large query that is not very effective.

What we *can* do however, is work with an [**`.alias(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#alias) and a `.filter(…)` to check if the number of matches is the required number so:

```
from django.db.models import Count

data = [1, 2]
Model.objects.alias(
    nmatch=Count('m2m_model', filter=Q(m2m_model__in=data), distinct=True)
).filter(nmatch=len(set(data)))
```

We thus first count the number of matches, and then we restrict that number to the number of unique ones in `data`.

As for the `MultiSelectFieldListFilter`, likely that still can be achieved, since such filters have a method to filter the queryset, so no `Q` object is necessary: we can use arbitrary code to filter the queryset properly. Indeed, see for example this implementation for a [**`SimpleListFilter`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/filters/#using-a-simplelistfilter)